# Is it ok to override a virtual method but provide no implementation?

Tags: oop, overriding, abstract

I'm trying to create a class heirachy for a game, there is an Item class which is the base class for all items in the game. The problem is that some derived items (like potion) might not implement some of the abstract methods defined by the item.

Is it ok for derived classes to implement an abstract method with "do nothing"?

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jJABN1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public abstract class Item
{
    public abstract void Use(); 
}

public class Potion : Item
{
    public override void Use()
    {
        // do nothing
        return;
    }
}

public class Sword : Item
{
    public override void Use()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sword used!");
        return;
    }
}
    
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        
        Item potion = new Potion();
        Item sword = new Sword();
        
        items.Add(potion);
        items.Add(sword);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            Item item = items[i];
            item.Use();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at a similar question at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/901f5dc9-5a2d-40e1-864c-5363c40cbc25/good-oop-design-empty-derived-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of [Robert Martin](http://cleancoder.com)'s SOLID Principles - [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) addresses this situation. It basically says that a client should not be exposed to methods it doesn't need.

An example of violating the *Interface Segregation Principle*:

```cs
// Abstraction

public abstract class Printer
{
    public abstract void Print();
    public abstract void Scan();
}


// Implementations

public class SomeAllInOnePrinter : Printer
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing...");
    }

    public override void Scan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scanning...");
    }
}

public class SomeBasicPrinter : Printer
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing...");
    }

    public override void Scan()
    {
        // Basic printers can't scan
    }
}
```

This is usually solved by separating an abstract class to multiple smaller abstract classes that can optionally inherit one other:

```cs
// Abstractions

public abstract class Printer
{
    public abstract void Print();
}

public abstract class AllInOnePrinter : Printer
{
    public abstract void Scan();
}


// Implementations

public class SomeAllInOnePrinter : AllInOnePrinter
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing...");
    }

    public override void Scan()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scanning...");
    }
}

public class SomeBasicPrinter : Printer
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Printing...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! i see now, that's very useful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there could be an edge-case (should be uncommon!) where a deriving class doesn't need to implement all the methods, in such a case I'd rather it to override and throw an error to signal the user that this method should not be used.

That said, in the provided example there is only one method, so the question is: if a derived class doesn't need this method - why do you need to inherit the abstract class to begin with? if it's just in order to provide an example that's understandable - but better improve the example to include other methods that *are* used in the derived class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I need to derive from the Item base class so that I can store both items in the same list? I have updated the example to include the list in the main function

Comment: @RichardBamford you didn't tag this question as c++ specific so I'm assuming this is a general OOP question. And as such, many OO languages allow the use of an `interface` which is different from an abstract class in the manner that a class may implement multiple interfaces (while most languages restrict inheritance to only a single class due to the [diamond-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)). In this specific context it sounds like an interface will be more suitable than an abstract class.